# How should I go about adding a code example to an existing answer to a question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-examples

I recently [tried to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2223572) this answer "[Resolve absolute path from relative path and/or file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645843/batch-file-resolve-absolute-path-from-relative-path-and-or-file-name/1645992#1645992)" and was slapped down with 
`"This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."` by all three reviewers. After reading up on that rejection reason I can understand, but I feel I am left without a good option for contributing a clarifying code example to an already good answer.

I felt the wording of the answer was correct, but for me it was a little hard to grasp when a simple code example would have been a lot clearer, but by itself would be insufficient of an answer.

The example I wanted to add was:

**example.bat**

```
@echo off
echo %%~dp0 is "%~dp0"
echo %%0 is "%0"
echo %%~dpnx0 is "%~dpnx0"
echo %%~f1 is "%~f1"
echo %%~dp0%%~1 is "%~dp0%~1"
```

if example.bat was placed in c:\temp\example.bat
and the command to execute it was run from c:\
as

```
c:\>temp\example.bat ..\windows
```

the result would be

```
%~dp0 is "c:\temp\"
%0 is "temp\example.bat"
%~dpnx0 is "c:\temp\example.bat"
%~f1 is "c:\Windows"
%~dp0%~1 is "c:\temp\..\windows"
```

How should I go about adding this valuable information to this "community wiki"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make it an answer. If it is useful it will be upvoted by the community and the problem will be solved. You are allowed to structure an answer like:

> `<Answerer A>` is correct, but to clarify, here is the code you would use to implement this: `<code>`

Answer (score 4):

With some difficulty.

Sadly, non-trivial edits are often rejected without due consideration. As Patashu notes, you can write an answer instead, and once you've garnered 2K rep on the site you can submit edits without needing approval - until then, accept that edits adding a non-trivial amount of content to an answer may well be rejected.

That said, I've gone ahead and added the examples - plus a bit more cleanup - to that particular answer.

Comment: Just to add support to Shog's answer, I'd emphasize that such an edit probably IS a good, helpful one, assuming the example is aligned with the original response, and the combined, edited answer is *better* than having two answers that together give you all the info.